# HTTP 102 Processing filter for Java

Tags: java, http, jetty

I have a web application based on a Jetty server. My problem is that I have some long running requests which can take up to a few minutes. Some of my clients do have a connection-timeout of some seconds though. So I though I could serve them with 102 PROCESSING responses to prevent the connection timeout.

I haven't found any sources or examples though on the internet, which makes me wonder if this is the right approach. I am for sure not the first persons trying to solve this problem :)

So anybody has a suggestion for making this work in Jetty? Maybe using Continuations? Or is there a hidden configuration option?

cheers
Philipp

Comment: You must investigate: 1. whether jetty can response "102 Processing"; 2. how many browsers support "102 Processing".

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking to use code 102 for the same purposes as you.

But it appears that HTTP response code 102 was never part of HTTP spec itself, but instead it was defined for WebDAV extensions. See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53238328/why-was-http-status-code-102-removed-from-http-1-1). So I doubt that there is any reasonable support for this response code in HTTP clients and servers.